# strpos() not working as expected?

Tags: php, foreach, strpos

I know the $a variable with the  tag is not properly formatted, however that's irrelevant to the issue.

The issue is that strpos is looking for a forward slash, /, in the value of each key in the array, but it is not printing.

```
$a = '<a target="" href="/test/url">test';
$a_expanded = explode("\"", $a);
echo print_r($a_expanded);
foreach($a_expanded as $num => $aspect) {
  echo $aspect;
  if ($contains_path = strpos($aspect, '/')) {
    echo $a_expanded[$num];
  }
}
```

It echos the array and each aspect, but will not echo the string with the forward slashes when found by strpos.

Comment: explode("\"", $a); ? not explode("\", $a); ?

Comment: Because you're doing an assignment inside the `if` statement. You need this instead: `if ($contains_path = (strpos($aspect, '/') !== FALSE)) {`

Comment: @AmalMurali it should still return TRUE, no?

Comment: @KA_lin I'm exploding on double quotes, the backslash is to escape the character.

Comment: My bad, it is my misstake

Comment: @CR47: Nope, because `strpos()` returns `FALSE` or `0` every time (which is a falsey value anyway).

Comment: @AmalMurali your fix worked, you can make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @CR47: You can just post it as answer yourself if you want.

Comment: strpos() returns 0 because in "/test/url" the first match is in the 0 position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strpos()` could either return `FALSE`, 0, or a non-zero value.

- If the needle occurs at the beginning of the haystack, `strpos()` returns 0.
- If it occurs elsewhere, it returns the respective position of the needle in the haystack.
- If needle wasn't found in the haystack, `strpos()` returns boolean `FALSE`.

I wasn't checking for strict equality, so the `if` statement always returned a falsey value, causing my code to not work.

```
if ($contains_path = strpos($aspect, '/'))
```

To fix the issue, you could use `!==`, which compares the type *and* value:

```
if ($contains_path = (strpos($aspect, '/') !== FALSE))
```

For more information, check the following links:

- http://php.net/strpos
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($contains_path = strpos($aspect, '/'))
```

should be

```
$contains_path = strpos($aspect, '/');
if ($contains_path !== false)
```

as strpos will return 0 when the string directly starts with a `/` (as it does, in your case). If strpos has no match, it returns false.

`if (0)` and `if (false)` are the same. So you need to do strict comparison (`=== or !==`) here.

Comment: `strpos()` never returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The position of found string might be 0 which is counted as false, you need to compare as `===`

```
if (false !== $contains_path = strpos($aspect, '/')) {
   echo $a_expanded[$num];
}
```